# Visual Studio Code - find and remove entire line

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have ~150 files that I need to remove the jQuery import from, as we have Webpack importing it automatically.

How can I achieve this with find and replace in vscode? I would like to remove a single line from each file and have the rest of the code shift up a line. I have the below regex, however, I'm not sure what I need to put in the replace field to remove the line.

[image]

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Try add `\n` to your search regex and replace with empty string.

In your case:
`^import \$ from 'jquery';$\n`

---

Update: [November 2018 (version 1.30)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_30#_multiline-search-input)

> Multiline search input
>
> Last month, we added support for multiline search. This month we improved the search UX to make it easier to use. Now, you can search with multiline text without having to write a regular expression. Type Shift+Enter in the search box to insert a newline, and the search box will grow to show your full multiline query. You can also copy and paste a multiline selection from the editor into the search box.

Comment: I had an issue with \n at the end matching only lines where the line-to-be-deleted is followed by a newline. Solved this by adding the \n at the start.

Comment: \n worked for some of mine, had to do \r\n to catch the others.

Answer (score 12):

As an update, let's say I need to delete `deployStage: 3` from the next block of code and also be sure I don't let the blank space:

```
  score:
    deployStage: 3
    ports:
      - container: 1000
        portName: tcp
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

I need this regex: `^.*deployStage.*[0-9]\n` as this:

[image]

The result is this:

```
  score:
    ports:
      - container: 1000
        portName: tcp
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

Comment: Tx. i noticed ,if you use the mouse to select the cursor upto the begining of word "ports" and copy paste the same as search word you can achieve the same . Thus no regex unless specifically a need for it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case clicking to `replace all` without entering anything in it worked. It worked like a find and delete all

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For example, I want deleting Foreign key in data models, I find words

```
public virtual
```

then replace

```
^.*public virtual.*$\n
```

affected lines

```cs
public virtual ICollection<ImportExternalTable> ImportExternalTables { get; set; } = new List<ImportExternalTable>();
```

[image]

[image]

In your case

```
^.*jquery.*$\n
```

Answer (score 0):

In the 'replace' input, just add a blank space. This will remove the selected lines and replace it with blank space. You can then remove that blank space by a code formatter such as Prettier and run that on all your files.

[image]

Comment: This will not remove the whole line, you must also match `\n`